# How can the max fee be corrected when building a transaction?

Tags: bitcoin-core, transaction-fees

Im not sure why i keep running into this problem, but what are the ways to correct the high fee error?   i have done settxfee etc.. is there a switch to indicate when building out the createrawtransaction -- sign --- send ?

absurdly-high-fee, 53064013 > 10000000 (code 256) (code -26)

Also is the following suppose to be populated once you sign/true .. or after its sent?

"vout": 0,
"scriptSig": {
"asm": "",
"hex": ""

Comment: When you use `createrawtransaction`, you have to do everything manually, including the selection of inputs and fee. The fee is defined by the difference between input amounts and output amounts. The error is there to help you: it is detecting that the transaction you'd be sending **does** have a huge fee, which you probably don't want to send.

Comment: I hope you are on testnet, because you are about to send half a bitcoin in fees.